# SVG animation не срабатывает в FF

Tags: javascript, svg, firefox, svg-animation

Коллеги есть такой код. Кнопка для плеера `play-pause`.

```js
let flag = true,
  pause = document.getElementById('pause'),
  play = document.getElementById('play');


document.getElementById('wrapper_svg_1').addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (flag == true) {
    pause.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    play.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
  console.log(flag);
});
```

```html
<play-pause id="playpause" play-pause custom>
  <svg id="wrapper_svg_1" viewBox="0 0 200 300" width="200" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <style>
                    #wrapper_svg_1 {
                        background: trensparent;
                    }
                    </style>
                    <path fill="grey" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" d="M100 100, 50 50, 50 250, 100 200z M100 100, 150 150, 150 150, 100 200z">
                        <animate id="pause" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur=".1s" to="M90 50, 50 50, 50 250, 90 250z M110 50, 150 50, 150 250, 110 250z" />
                        <animate id="play" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur=".1s" to="M100 100, 50 50, 50 250, 100 200z M100 100, 150 150, 150 150, 100 200z" />
                    </path>
                </svg>

</play-pause>
```

Особо рассказывать, что тут к чему, думаю не стоит.

Единственная проблема в том, что данная анимация на срабатывает в FF.
При клике как есть изначальная фигура так и остается.

Пол дня ковыряюсь не могу понять, что к чему и почему так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Коллеги, оказалось все просто.  Формат атрибута `dur="n"` у меня `dur=".1s"`, что FF и не нравиться. Формат атрибута `dur="n"` должен быть такой `dur="0.1s"` и все заработает

```js
let flag = true,
  pause = document.getElementById('pause'),
  play = document.getElementById('play');


document.getElementById('wrapper_svg_1').addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (flag == true) {
    pause.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    play.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
  console.log(flag);
});
```

```html
<play-pause id="playpause" play-pause custom>
  <svg id="wrapper_svg_1" viewBox="0 0 200 300" width="200" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <style>
                    #wrapper_svg_1 {
                        background: trensparent;
                    }
                    </style>
                    <path fill="grey" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" d="M100 100, 50 50, 50 250, 100 200z M100 100, 150 150, 150 150, 100 200z">
                        <animate id="pause" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="0.1s" to="M90 50, 50 50, 50 250, 90 250z M110 50, 150 50, 150 250, 110 250z" />
                        <animate id="play" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="0.1s" to="M100 100, 50 50, 50 250, 100 200z M100 100, 150 150, 150 150, 100 200z" />
                    </path>
                </svg>

</play-pause>
```